# how to make cloud recognition video playback in unity3d using json

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Friends, i'm planning to do a cloud based videoplayback project in unity. In my project, cloud targets are detecting but videos are not playing. I need to do json based cloud recognition to play videos but i don't know how to do that.

This is my code for your reference:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;
using UnityEngine.UI;

/// <summary>
/// This MonoBehaviour implements the Cloud Reco Event handling for this sample.
/// It registers itself at the CloudRecoBehaviour and is notified of new search results.
/// </summary>
public class SimpleCloudHandler : MonoBehaviour, ICloudRecoEventHandler
{
    #region PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES

    // CloudRecoBehaviour reference to avoid lookups
    private CloudRecoBehaviour mCloudRecoBehaviour;
    // ImageTracker reference to avoid lookups
    private ObjectTracker mImageTracker;

    private bool mIsScanning = false;

    private string mTargetMetadata = "";
    private GameObject videoObject;

    #endregion // PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES



    #region EXPOSED_PUBLIC_VARIABLES

    /// <summary>
    /// can be set in the Unity inspector to reference a ImageTargetBehaviour that is used for augmentations of new cloud reco results.
    /// </summary>
    public ImageTargetBehaviour ImageTargetTemplate;


    #endregion

    #region UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

    /// <summary>
    /// register for events at the CloudRecoBehaviour
    /// </summary>
    void Start()
    {
        // register this event handler at the cloud reco behaviour
        CloudRecoBehaviour cloudRecoBehaviour = GetComponent<CloudRecoBehaviour>();
        if (cloudRecoBehaviour)
        {
            cloudRecoBehaviour.RegisterEventHandler(this);
        }

        // remember cloudRecoBehaviour for later
        mCloudRecoBehaviour = cloudRecoBehaviour;

    }

    #endregion // UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS


    #region ICloudRecoEventHandler_IMPLEMENTATION

    /// <summary>
    /// called when TargetFinder has been initialized successfully
    /// </summary>
    public void OnInitialized()
    {
        // get a reference to the Image Tracker, remember it
        mImageTracker = (ObjectTracker)TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// visualize initialization errors
    /// </summary>
    public void OnInitError(TargetFinder.InitState initError)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// visualize update errors
    /// </summary>
    public void OnUpdateError(TargetFinder.UpdateState updateError)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// when we start scanning, unregister Trackable from the ImageTargetTemplate, then delete all trackables
    /// </summary>
    public void OnStateChanged(bool scanning) {
        mIsScanning = scanning;
        if (scanning) {
            // clear all known trackables
            ObjectTracker tracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker> ();
            tracker.TargetFinder.ClearTrackables (false);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles new search results
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="targetSearchResult"></param>
    public void OnNewSearchResult(TargetFinder.TargetSearchResult targetSearchResult)
    {
        // duplicate the referenced image target
        GameObject newImageTarget = Instantiate(ImageTargetTemplate.gameObject) as GameObject;



        GameObject augmentation = null;

        string model_name = targetSearchResult.MetaData;


        if( augmentation != null )
            augmentation.transform.parent = newImageTarget.transform;

        // enable the new result with the same ImageTargetBehaviour:

        //Debug.Log("Metadata value is " + model_name );
        //VideoPlaybackBehaviour video = ImageTargetTemplate.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<VideoPlaybackBehaviour>();
        mTargetMetadata = model_name;
        if (targetSearchResult.MetaData == "a") {
            ImageTargetAbstractBehaviour imageTargetBehaviour = mImageTracker.TargetFinder.EnableTracking (targetSearchResult, newImageTarget);
        }


        if (!mIsScanning)
        {
            // stop the target finder
            mCloudRecoBehaviour.CloudRecoEnabled = true;
        }


    }


    #endregion // ICloudRecoEventHandler_IMPLEMENTATION
}
```

Comment: So...you have a lot of code here which looks like it's built by Vuforia, but you don't anywhere have anything for the target being recognized or do anything with your `videoObject`. We can't help you without a clear problem statement.

Comment: I've attached, video object with image target. Please check that screenshot by using this link (http://imgur.com/a/lt57i).  And if i give video url in "videoplayback behaviour" path it plays video but it's playing same video for all the images in my cloud db. We saw many forums regarding cloud reco video playback everyone said that it can be done using JSON. But I don't know how to do that. Please help me out with alternate solution.